# Perl syntax error when opening a file

Tags: perl, variables, syntax, scope

I have written a sub routine and when I run my program, I am getting the error message : "syntax error at line74, near 'open' "
Is it possible the error is because I've used my to declare the content array?

```
my @content = do{
        local $/ = \$width;
        <$fh>;
    }



    open(OUT, ">", $outfile) or die "cannot open \n"; #this is line 74
    binmode(OUT);
    foreach ( @content ){
        print OUT $_;
    }

    close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing semicolon in line before that,

```
my @content = do{
    local $/ = \$width;
    <$fh>;
}; # semicolon
```